# My Closure Won't Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, closures, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to prevent polluting the global space with a bunch of variables, and since I can't use `let` yet, I have to make closures. So I have this basic webpage with a bootstrap accordion, each card hiding different examples. In one I have a form that asks in a `<select>` what your position is. OnChange it will grab the eventData object, call spillObject() (the closure method), and populate another accordion card with its contents. **It works**, but problem is, **I can't seem to make it work as a simple closure**. Nothing seems to happen, and since you can't debug a closure, other than making it spit out console.logs() everywhere, I can't find out what's wrong with it.

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {

    $("#position").change( /*(*/ function(eventData) {
        var div = $('#explodedObject');
        div.html('');
        var result = spillObject('#explodedObject', eventData, '');
        /*};*/
        div.append(result);

    } /*)()*/ );


    var spillObject = (function(dataParent, obj, heirarchy) {
        var heirArr = heirarchy == '' ? [] : heirarchy.split('_');
        heirArr.push(1);
        var teir = heirArr.length - 1;

        var id = "#collapse" + heirArr.join('');
        var headerID = 'header' + heirArr.join('');



        var card = document.createElement('div');
        card.classList.add('card');


        var cardHeader = document.createElement('div');
        cardHeader.classList.add('card-header');
        cardHeader.id = headerID;
        var h5 = document.createElement('h5');
        h5.classList.add('mb-0');
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.classList.add('btn', 'btn-link');
        button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'collapse');
        button.setAttribute('data-target', id);


        var cardBody = document.createElement('div');
        cardBody.classList.add('card-body');
        var collapse = document.createElement('div');

        collapse.id = id.substr(1, id.length - 1);
        collapse.classList.add('collapse');
        collapse.setAttribute('data-parent', dataParent);


        var dl = document.createElement('dl');
        dl.id = '#' + heirArr.join('');
        var dt;
        var dd;
        var x;
        return function() {

        for (x in obj) {
                dt = document.createElement('dt');
                dd = document.createElement('dd');

                dt.innerHTML = x;
                if (typeof obj[x] == 'object' && heirArr.length < 3) {
                    heirArr[teir]++;

                    innerObj = spillObject(dl.id, obj[x], heirArr.join('_'));
                    dd.appendChild(innerObj);
                } else {
                    dd.innerHTML = obj[x];
                }

                dl.append(dt);
                dl.append(dd);
            }

            heirArr.pop();
            heirArr[heirArr.length - 1] = parseInt(heirArr[heirArr.length - 1]);
            heirArr[heirArr.length - 1]--;

            collapse.appendChild(cardBody);

            button.innerHTML = 'card ' + heirArr.join('.');
            h5.appendChild(button);
            cardHeader.appendChild(h5);
            card.appendChild(cardHeader);
            card.appendChild(collapse);
            cardBody.appendChild(dl);
            return card;
        };
    });

})();
```

More basically, I'm following this template:

```
var method = (function(param){
    var var1 = 'default value';

    return function(){
        var1 = 'something else';
    };
})();
```

Should I have used this one instead, and if so would it hide the variables?

```
var method2 = function(param) {
        return function() {
            var var1 = 'default value';
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the result of `spillObject` is a function, you must then also call that function. Here's a simplified version of what you are doing.

```js
var spillObject = (function(dataParent, obj, heirarchy) {
  
  console.log('first function')
  
  return function() {
    console.log('second function')
  };
  
});

var result = spillObject()

console.log(result)

result()
```

Comment: I always forget those. Where do I put the params? Also, this didn't work.

Comment: Everything in the `spillObject` function is NOT in the global namespace, you shouldn't need to have another function inside of it.

Comment: Okay. That's a relief, and the whole reason why I was doing this. The third-to-last sentence on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) had me thinking that an alternative design would make them public/global.

Comment: That `add` example is very specialized. The main point is, once inside of  ANY function, using `var` will be local to that function and NOT a global.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. So wait, why use a closure then, if not for this reason? Is it just for the add example?